# Book about female special forces officer whose Alpha and Beta ports were turned off

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book I am looking for is about a female special forces officer. Her Alpha and Beta ports were turned off after an incident and she had to place her hand inside of a helmet to connect to it. Later in the book she steals a ship and escapes a space station. I'm aware this isn't much to go off of.

Comment: Please go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and try answering the questions there, answering them into your question. It will help us help you.

Comment: When did you read it? What language? Do you remember any character names or names of places?

Comment: What are alpha and beta ports? I’m not a biologist, so perhaps this is a portion of the female anatomy with which I am unfamiliar. Or is this slang of some sort? Was she a cyborg?

Comment: I suspect that the protagonist was some sort of a cyborg with some sort of enhancements for her job as a special forces officer.  And when her employment was terminated her enhancements were shut off, but maybe she can reach inside her helmet to temporarily reactivate them.

Comment: "Alpha" and "beta" referred to the implants members of the Imperial Cadre from *In Fury Born* use to interface with their equipment. Members of the military typically have one set, Cadre troops have two which allow them to literally do two things at once.

Answer (score 7):

It might be the book below - Apart from the hand in a helmet to reconnect her ports the rest fits.

[In Fury Born by David Weber (2005)](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/w/david-weber/in-fury-born.htm)

Imperial Intelligence couldn't find them, the Imperial Fleet couldn't catch them, and local defenses couldn't stop them. It seemed the planet-wrecking pirates were invincible. But they made a big mistake when they raided ex-commando leader Alicia DeVries' quiet home world, tortured and murdered her family, and then left her for dead. 
Alicia decided to turn "pirate" herself, and stole a cutting-edge AI ship from the Empire to start her vendetta. Her fellow veterans think she's gone crazy, the Imperial Fleet has shoot-on-sight orders. And of course the pirates want her dead, too. 
But Alicia DeVries has two allies nobody knows about, allies as implacable as she is: a self-aware computer, and a creature from the mists of Old Earth's most ancient legends. And this trio of furies won't rest until vengeance is served.

This is an expanded version of Path of the Fury from 1992 which includes a prequel story

Comment: It's *In Fury Born*. There's nothing in there about having to put her hand inside a helmet (I reread the book recently), but everything else is from there.

Comment: "Alpha and beta ports" is a dead ringer for *In Fury Born*.